# Entity Framework / Azure Web Service model design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I am doing some prototyping and have a small database (4 related tables) which I developed an Entity Framework 6 project around (DLL with models for the tables).  I've added an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web App to the solution that includes Repository interfaces/implementations under the model folder.  The Repositories add interfaces for CRUD operations against the EF project.  The Web App has a set of controllers providing REST interface through the repositories. Standard stuff I believe.

The issue that I have is I want to create an aggregate class the wrappers types (models) defined in the EF and return that aggregate in response to a Get request.  The question is where do I define this aggregate object?  The EF project? (and how?).  An independent class library (usable by a client)?  The Web App?

Trying to keep all the model definitions in the same place that understood by a client and Web App service at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want here is the DTO (Data Transfer Object) pattern. See [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) for basic explanation of the pattern. The idea is that you define a set of classes distinct from your data access objects (EF classes in your case), whose purpose is to relay data between your REST interface and its clients. If you have C# clients to whom you want to make the class definitions visible for simplicity then I would suggest putting the DTO class definitions in their own class library project and have the server and client both reference that dll.

Comment: Well kind of.  Using class based models to exchange data between a client and web service.  The real question is where should those models live that they can be shared between client(s), EF, and the service so there is not a lot of redundant code.

Comment: As I said in the last sentence I would put them in their own dll and reference that from client & server projects. To expand on that in cases like this with our projects we often put these kind of shared dlls into versioned Nuget packages that we serve from a private nuget server.

Comment: I gotcha and that makes sense.  That still leaves me with the model contained within the EF project.  Do you use EF for your projects in that way?  How are the models kept in synch?

Comment: Yes, using EF as the DAL behind repository interfaces is a pattern we use in some of our projects. The decision about where the EF classes live is usually driven by who uses it. It often starts out in the project that first uses it. If no other projects ever need the same DAL it stays there. As soon as a second project needs it we refactor it out into a common package.